# Short syntax for ignoring directory/ and .directory/ in .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

Is there a short syntax for ignoring

```
directory/
.directory/
```

at my .gitignore (something in the lines of `\.?directory/`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Gitignore uses glob patterns, which only supports the '?' and '*' wildcards for "one arbitrary character" or "any number of arbitrary characters", respectively.